# When building android my linux box fails to build due to being unable to access site_perl

Tags: android, ubuntu, build

When I'm building android image my linux machine fails to build. The error is the following:

cannot access /tools/oss/packages/x86_64-2.6/subversion/default/perl5/lib/site_perl./5.8.8/*multi

Has anyone encountered this issue ?

Please let me know.